# What is the purpose of this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html

I was poking around with inspect element and came across this:

```
NumberOfDivsToRandomDisplay = 10;

var CookieName = 'DivRamdomValueCookie';

function DisplayRandomDiv() {
    var r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * NumberOfDivsToRandomDisplay);
    if (NumberOfDivsToRandomDisplay > 1) {
        var ck = 0;
        var cookiebegin = document.cookie.indexOf(CookieName + "=");
        if (cookiebegin > -1) {
            cookiebegin += 1 + CookieName.length;
            cookieend = document.cookie.indexOf(";", cookiebegin);
            if (cookieend < cookiebegin) {
                cookieend = document.cookie.length;
            }
            ck = parseInt(document.cookie.substring(cookiebegin, cookieend));
        }
        while (r == ck) {
            r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * NumberOfDivsToRandomDisplay);
        }
        document.cookie = CookieName + "=" + r;
    }
    for (var i = 1; i <= NumberOfDivsToRandomDisplay; i++) {
        document.getElementById("randomdiv" + i).style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById("randomdiv" + r).style.display = "block";
}
DisplayRandomDiv();
```

What is its purpose? Just curious, thanks :)

Comment: Looks like it displays random div elements based on some cookie values.

Comment: Is there some particular line (or lines) that you do not understand? You should make an effort to understand the code and then explain clearly what you do and don't understand. That way, answers won't waste time explaining what you already understand and can focus on what you didn't understand.

Comment: Sorry I guess I worded my question poorly - I suppose I *understand the code itself* and what it **does**, I don't really understand in what situation you would want to do this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code assumes you have `div`'s with ID's "randomdiv1", "randomdiv2" etc.

It then reads the cookie named `DivRamdomValueCookie`. If it's present, it contains an integer value which will be the ID of the div currently shown ("randomdiv" + value of the cookie).

Then, it will hide all the divs, and then show one of the divs, different from the div whose ID was stored in the cookie. If the cookie was not present, it will display random div.

This script has a hard-coded number of div's in a `NumberOfDivsToRandomDisplay` variable.

Answer (score 0):

toggling of divs that also stores a particular div state for some time.

http://ipankaj.net/how-to-display-multiple-testimonials-randomly-on-your-website/